# Convert .shp files to an excel spreadsheet programmatically

Tags: php, javascript, gis, shapefile

I have a file in .shp format and I need it to convert it to an Excel spreadsheet programmatically. I want to do this using PHP or JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Once I've used small PHP lib ShapeFile, you can get it in [phpclasses.org](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/6786.html). Although it is a bit of not so good design, it works.

Here is a little example from my own code:

```
require_once 'lib/ShapeFile.inc.php';
$shp = new ShapeFile($filename, array('noparts' => false));
if ($shp->getError() !== '')
  print_r($shp->getError());
else
{
  $records = array();
  while ($record = $shp->getNext())
  {
    $dbf_data = $record->getDbfData();
    $shp_data = $record->getShpData();

    //Dump the information
    $obj = array(
      'type' => $shp->getShpTypeName($record->getShpType())
    );

    $obj['shape'] = $shp_data;
    $obj['meta'] = $dbf_data;

    $records[] = $obj;
  }
}

print_r($records);
```

So, after that `$records` contain all the data from shapefile. Of course, you will need some time to figure out what shapefile is and what data it can hold (assuming you are not familiar with it). Start from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile). Actually there are bunch of arrays with some labels.

Then use some php excel lib (just seek in so) and you're done :)

Comment: Thanks alot brother! Let me try this.

Comment: its giving an error:
Call to a member function assign() on a non-object

Comment: of course it is given error, cause you have no object $view :) It is just an artifact from existing code. It means put a variable into view to be available in template. Code is just a reference. remove line with `$view->assign` and do print_r($records) at the end.

Comment: Just a note: Ran into some trouble running WAMP 2.2.22 and PHP 5.4.3 and `ShapeFile.inc.php`. As of PHP 5.3 `php_dbase` is no longer included. I got a working extension here... http://hrazdil.info/blog/414-php-dbase-extension-for-php-5-4-windows-nts-ts-vc9