# Generating "SHAPEFILES " from co-ordinates using PHP AND MYSQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, arcgis

Can anyone please help me to generate "**SHAPEFILES** "  from co-ordinates using **PHP AND MYSQL**?

I have the latitude and longitude of points in my database. So I have to generate one shapefile for the same [dimension]. i.e. separate shape files for points, lines and polygons.

Can anyone please guide me how to generate the shapefiles. The shape file i used to create the layer in the **ARCGIS**. These points are saved from my android mobile application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look on this link, [Bytefall Shapefile PHP Library](http://bfshapefiles.sourceforge.net/docs.php). It's PHP library to write shapefile. Hope it will be help you.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is looking for an actively maintained free and open source library to read and write any ESRI Shapefile natively in PHP without any other dependency, [PHP Shapefile v3](https://github.com/gasparesganga/php-shapefile) has just been released.

Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26915189) for details.